# Sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, notation

Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. I have seen it written before that $(x_n)\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct or is it abuse of notation since sequences aren’t simply just sets.

Comment: That notation is acceptable, but is generally made clear by accompanying text.

Comment: One can think of the elements of a  sequence of real numbers as being a countable subset of the real numbers. So the notation merely indicates that the sequence at hand is a subset of the real numbers, indicating that we have a real-valued sequence of real numbers. Other than that, yes you're right; this is an abuse of notation because a sequence isn't a set, it can be described as a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It's an abuse of notation, but a very common one.

Comment: @Christoph indeed. I've also seen $\{x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ used to refer to the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. }x = x_n\}$, i.e. the sequence considered as a mere set with the order forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $ (x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N} $ be a real sequence.

Here is what we are allowed to write :

$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N)\;\; x_n\in \Bbb R$$

$$(x_n)\in \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$$

$$\{x_n : n\in \Bbb N \}\subset \Bbb R$$

Comment: Are you saying mathematicians write $(x_n)\subseteq R$ despite it not being *allowed*!?